# 'UNTRUSTED Good signature' message by enigmail on thunderbird after I moved the keys to a different machine

Tags: gnupg, thunderbird

I recently moved my keys to a different machine and configured Enigmail on the Thunderbird on the new machine. Though I am able to encrypt and decrypt files alternatively in both machine now(which I guess means that the keys got imported to new machine correctly). However now when I send a mail even to myself, I get this message that the signature if UNtrusted. How do I fix this. I have tried to sign my public key myself as some posts suggested but it is saying that the key is already signed by me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In thunderbird, open the `KeyManagement` dialog in the `OpenPGP` menu, then search for your key or hit `Display All Keys by Default`. Then you can right-click on the key and select `Set Owner Trust`. There you can set the tust level for the key.

Alternatively, you should get the same option when clicking on `Details` in the PGP signature area above the message.